# Can I alter the block editor's paste text behavior?

Tags: javascript, block-editor, bug

In the [sample editor](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/), create a paragraph with just `Hello world`, copy it and--while still selected--paste over it. You get the expected pasted text.

But if there's a leading word with a colon (`Hello: world`) then pasting puts the entire text into 1 link. I don't think I've seen this auto-linking in any other WYSIWYG editor, but I don't know that it's a bug.

Is this a feature that can be disabled?

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently [Gutenberg bug 24895](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/24895).

The problem being that `Hello:` is a [well-formed URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax), so WP shouldn't rely on `new URL()` alone to recognize a pasted link.

```
new URL('Hello: world');
```